# How to handle build events/progress using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I need a way to send build events/progress during the build process.

All I have is roughly:

```
var proj = Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(csprojDir);
var consoleLogger = new Microsoft.Build.Logging.ConsoleLogger();
proj.Build(consoleLogger);
```

But I can't find a way to handle events (e.g. some `Action` or delegate of any kind that receives events).

Any idea how catch those?

Answer (score 0):

Write your own custom logger and pass an instance of your logger to the [`Build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.build?view=msbuild-17-netcore) method. There are overloads of `Build` that accept an `IEnumerable<ILogger>` so you can pass both the `consoleLogger` and your custom logger.

[`ILogger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.ilogger?view=msbuild-17-netcore&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) defines an `Initialize(IEventSource)` method. [`IEventSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.ieventsource?view=msbuild-17-netcore) has the events you are probably looking for.

There is example code (the same example) in both the [`IEventSource` Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.ieventsource?view=msbuild-17-netcore) and [`ILogger` Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.ilogger?view=msbuild-17-netcore&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) documentation.